# img tag being stripped out of front end

Tags: wygwam

I place an image on a page using the file manager. I can see it in the editor, but when the image is displayed in the front end, all I see is the image path and not the image. When I look at the source code, I see that the image tag is removed. I am using Wygwam but I have disabled "Restrict Allowed HTML" 
ExpressionEngine v2.10.1 - Build Date: 20150501 -

Answer (score 1):

Look at Admin -> Channel Administration -> Channels, then select Edit Preferences for the Channel you're using to output the entry mentioned. Search down the preferences for "Channel Posting Preferences" and you'll see "Allow image URLs in channel entries?". Ensure this is set to Yes.

[image]

Comment: Glad that did the trick, G. Ruga. Since this solved the issue for you, please "accept" Peter's answer. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)